# Сколько серверов у mail.ru?

Tags: highload, mail.ru

Кто-то знает, где можно узнать инфу по нагрузкам mail.ru и их аппаратной части?
Например, для [ВК есть такое](http://highload.com.ua/post/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%83+%D0%92%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5+%28VK%29%3F).

Comment: Если брать целиком **Mail.Ru Group** то VK нервно курит по сравнению.

Comment: nslookup дает только один IP адрес почтового сервера (у гугла 5, а у ibm 10). 

Но, почти наверняка, это даже не сервер, а load balancer.